# Contains one of several values

Tags: python, loops, contains

I have a dataframe `df` with column `x`  and a list `lst =["apple","peach","pear"]`

```
df  
x               
apple234  
pear231  
banana233445
```

If row1 in `df["x"]` contains any of the values in `lst`: then `1` else `0`

Final data should look like this:

```
df  
x  y  
apple234  -- 1  
pear231 -- 1    
banana233445 - 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with regex `|` for join all values of list, last cast boolean mask to `0,1` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
lst =["apple","peach","pear"]

df['y'] = df['x'].str.contains('|'.join(lst)).astype(int)
print (df)
              x  y
0      apple234  1
1       pear231  1
2  banana233445  0
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked. However, I don't understand fully the logic behind it if you could explain the '.contains('|'.join(lst)

Comment: It is really simple - `print('|'.join(lst))` -> `apple|peach|pear` it means check if `apple` OR `peach` OR `pear` is in column - [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) filter it by this joined string.